# R: Building formulas from strings in with.mids()

Tags: r, regression, lm, r-mice, imputation

I want to be able to run a regression on a `mids` object returned by `mice()`, based on a formula constructed from a string. For an ordinary regression (without imputation) this is easy:

```
library(mice)
for (x in c('age','hyp','chl')) {
  regx <- lm(data=nhanes2,paste('bmi ~',x))
  print(summary(regx)$coefficients)
}
```

I think doing the same thing on an imputed dataset should look something like this:

```
imp <- mice(nhanes2,printFlag = FALSE)
for (x in c('age','hyp','chl')) {
  regx <- with(data=imp,exp=lm(paste('bmi ~',x)))
  summary(pool(regx))
}
```

R tells me, however, that `object 'bmi' was not found`.

```
reg <- with(data=imp,exp=lm(bmi ~ age))
summary(pool(reg))
```

works just fine, but requires that I hard-code column names instead of supplying a string variable.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you provided no example. but `formula` is the function you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `lm` *does* accept a character string in place of a formula but it seems not within `with.mids` so convert it to a formula yourself:

```
f <- function(nm) {
     s <- paste("bmi", nm, sep = "~")
     regx <- with(imp, lm(as.formula(s)))
     summary(pool(regx))
}
Map(f, names(nhanes)[-2])
```

**Note:** You may wish to report this to the mice package maintainer.